# Read database during an entity framework migration (select query)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I know I can use the `Sql` method to update data during a migration, and it works great for simple things that can be expressed in pure SQL.

I also know I could use a `Seed` method but that would feel like a hack (the code I want to write has to be executed once, when the migration is executed).

In my current case, I need to strip HTML tags from a column, and write that to a new column added in the migration. I already have a C# method that does exactly that. What I want to do, is iterate over each row in C#, and generate a SQL statement for each row that will update the row with the corresponding HTML-stripped text.

More generally, I think being able to read the database in C# during a migration could be handy in a lot of situations. Doing so within the migration transaction would be perfect, but for that I need to retrieve the SQL connection that Entity Framework internally uses for the migration.

So far I've found no way to execute a SQL query that returns results. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer also to transform the data in migration files over the Seed method.

Updating the data should not be a problem, you can just do as shown in the line code below and  you can also passing the parameters from C# in the SQL string:

```
Sql("UPDATE TableName SET MyValueInMinutes= -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CurrentTime, 0)";
```

**The problem by data reading**! In reality you will never need to handle the data tranformation in C#, normally you create everything in SQL server (Stored procedure and functions and SQL stametents) and you can just call them from the migration file at the time point when you need them or when the data are ready to be trasformed. But I think you are not a database programmer, that why you are trying to handle the data in C#.

Here is an example how to iterate over the rows and I will search for a given text and find for you a free available 'AnyText'+Counter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_FindFreeName  
@toBeFindName nvarchar(MAX) OUT  
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @LoopCounter INTEGER 
SET @LoopCounter = 1 
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT @toBeFindName FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE Name = @toBeFindName) 
  BEGIN 
      SET   @toBeFindName = 'AnyText', @LoopCounter) 
      SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1 
  END 
END
```

Then you can called form C#:

```
var cSharpName = string.Empty;
Sql("exec sp_FindFreeName @toBeFindName=@"+ cSharpName +" OUTPUT");
```

where cSharpName given from C#.

The third why to do that you can also write your own Code First Migration Operations. You have to define your SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator as described in Rowan blog:

https://romiller.com/2013/02/27/ef6-writing-your-own-code-first-migration-operations/

***Conclusion:***

If you really want to read the data in the migration files then you have to use for example: SqlDataReader and you have to read also the connection string from App.config.

In most use cases you can do everything inside the SQL Server. Just create your data tranfsormation SQL scripts and execute them from the desired location.

You can use Extensions and SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator to do that in a cleaner way then the DataReader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you've guessed, I'm not too comfortable with SQL (and neither are my co-workers), and, well, I suppose I could write the whole website in SQL, but we've chosen C# as a much more convenient language for anything beyond simple database queries (such as parsing HTML, including malformed HTML). I'll take a look at the migration `Operations`, but at a first glance, they don't provide a database connection either (you can just blindly export SQL strings?). I'd like to avoid creating a distinct connection/transaction to the database if possible.

Comment: @youen then use The seed method for migration. The seed method will be called X time during the migration at each migration level one time. use If esle ... to find in which level your currently working and then you can just use very easy in C# as normal to add or remove or update the data. do not forget to vote and makr the answer if this solve your problem ^^

Comment: @youen one thing is still important there are 2 types of the Seed methods, one for Init and one for the Migration. Use the migration Seed, read this plz https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: thanks for the precision, I did not know there were two `Seed` methods. But if I understand correctly, there is no `Seed` method specific to one migration, that would run once, right after that migration is executed (and before the next migrations). That would definitely be useful, and solve my current problem, but it doesn't work that way, does it? Even if it did, it would still be limited because sometimes it is needed to interleave data initialization within schema changes (for example, populate a column after its creation, but before setting a unique index on it).

Comment: Since no one provided a better answer, I'm accepting this one ; especially for this part : "you have to use SqlDataReader and you have to read also the connection string from App.config". This seems to be the only answer to my specific question, even if it really isn't a nice way to do it.